# if внутри try except

Tags: python, python-3.x

Так работает:

```
    try:
        connector()
        stdin, stdout, stderr = client.exec_command('ifconfig')
        data = stdout.read() + stderr.read()
        print(data)

    except Exception as e:
        error_log = str(e)
        print('error_log')
file.close()
```

Так  тоже работает:

```
    if a1 in str(data):
        stdin, stdout, stderr = client.exec_command('ifconfig')
        data = stdout.read() + stderr.read()
        print(data)
    if a2 in str(data):
        stdin, stdout, stderr = client.exec_command('ls')
        data = stdout.read() + stderr.read()
        print(data)
file.close()
```

А как их совместить? Что бы `if` был внутри `try`.. `except`.

Comment: Просто вставить if'ы внутрь try-блока.

Answer (score 1):

попройте так:

```
def cli_exec(client, cmd):
    try:
        #connector()
        stdin, stdout, stderr = client.exec_command(cmd)
        data = stdout.read() + stderr.read()
        return data
    except Exception as e:
        error_log = str(e)
        print('error_log')
    finally:
        return None
```

---

```
if a1 in str(data):
    data = cli_exec(client, 'ifconfig')
if a2 in str(data):
    data = cli_exec(client, 'ls')
```

Comment: можно один вызов: `data = get_output(client, command)` где `command` в if-ветках определяется.

Comment: @jfs, можно и так...